# How can you get a variable's value given its name in korn shell?

Tags: ksh

Is there a way in ksh to get a variable's value when you have been given the name of the variable?

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
var_name=$1  #pretend here that the user passed the string "PATH"
echo ${$var_name}  #echo value of $PATH -- what do I do here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_name=$1  #pretend here that the user passed the string "PATH"
printenv    $var_name
```

Comment: printenv will only work for exported variables.  Normal shell variables will not appear empty.  I would recommend @Kevin's answer instead, if ksh is old, and does not support nameref.

Answer (score 9):

```
eval `echo '$'$var_name`
```

echo concatenates a '$' to the variable name inside $var_name, eval evaluates it to show the value.

EDIT:
The above isn't quite right.  The correct answer is with no backticks.

```
eval echo '$'$var_name
```

Comment: I tried this on cygwin and linux, but it didn't work. It works if you remove the backticks:
eval echo '$'$var_name

Comment: this is a more general solution than the "printenv" one, which only applies to environment variables

Answer (score 2):

`printenv` is not a ksh builtin and may not always be present.  For older ksh versions, prior to *ksh93*, the eval 'expression' method works best.

A powerful method in ksh93 is to use indirection variables
with 'nameref' or 'typeset -n'.

Define and verify a *nameref* variable that refers to `$PATH`:

```
$ nameref indirect=PATH
$ print $indirect
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

See how the *nameref* variable changes when we change `PATH`:

```
$ PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
$ print $indirect
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Show ksh version and the alias for `nameref`:

```
$ type nameref
nameref is an alias for 'typeset -n'
$ echo ${.sh.version}
Version JM 93t+ 2010-02-02
```

Answer (score 0):

For one step above your answer (I spent a lot of time trying to find both these answers). The below will allow you to export a dynamic variable and then recall it dynamically:

```
echo -n "Please provide short name for path:"
read PATH_SHORTCUT
echo -n "Please provide path:"
read PATH
eval export \${PATH_SHORTCUT}_PATH="${PATH}"
eval echo Path shortcut: ${PATH_SHORTCUT} set to \$"${PATH_SHORTCUT}_PATH".
```